# Does everyone get the same set of Mystery quests for unlocking?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

Starting at level 36, proceeding ahead needs either a payment, pestering Facebook friends or solving 3 'mystery quests', one per day. The difficulty levels of these seem to be highly inconsistent: I've had one which almost solved itself with a few moves, and recently a far harder one where I was stuck for a couple of days.

Are these quests same for all players per check point, or are they randomized on each client? If the latter, is there any way to 'reset' the randomization to receive a set of new quests, if the current ones include some particularly hard level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have to disagree with Young Guilo. The mystery quests are not the same for each user. They are previously beaten levels, which seem to require a higher score.

I, myself had to restart the game (due to wiping my phone) and at level 36, I did not receive the same mystery quests as the first time.

So in answer to your specific questions:

> 1) Are these quests same for all players per check point, or are they
>   randomized on each client?

They are not the same per check point. It might be based on how many stars you have received total or on specific levels, but I am more inclined to believe that they are random for each client.

> 2) If the latter, is there any way to 'reset' the randomization to
>   receive a set of new quests, if the current ones include some
>   particularly hard level?

Unfortunately, I don't know of a way that this can be done. This doesn't mean that it is not possible though.

I found [this](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/unlocking-new-episodes-in-candy-crush-saga-mystery-quests/), which isn't an official source, but confirms that they currently seem to be picked at random.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone gets the same quests and are not randomly generated. If you're stuck on a harder one look it up to find quides and tips on how to solve your problem.

Comment: This is incorrect, everyone definitely does not get the same quests.

Comment: Agreed with @NickBayley - my wife and I were playing and we got different quests at the same point.

Comment: @AdamV Thanks for corroborating Nick's answer. This one seems incorrect, unaccepting.

Answer (score 0):

They are different for everyone, I've been on the same level with friends and all the quest are different. If I'm not mistaken I sometimes think they give you one or two out of the three that you had trouble with!!